# Form Does not update database sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am facing issues with the connection of a form with the database, when I am trying to update a record using Sinatra.

I created a route and a form in a view.
At first the form connects to the `get` route and brings the relevant data. However, when I modify the fields and  press the submit button to update the database, the record does not updated.

```
get'/users/:id/edit'do
   # see the User we want to edit 
   @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
   #Assign the values to all properties
   @user.username = @user.username
   @user.password = @user.password
   @user.description =@user.description
   @user.city = @user.city
   @user.save
   erb:edit
 end

 put 'users/:id/edit' do
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    #Assign the values to all properties
    @user.username = @user.username
    @user.password = @user.password
    @user.description =@user.description
    @user.city = @user.city
    @user.save
 end
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="users/:id/edit" method="post" id="edit">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
    User ID : :<%=@user.id%> <br>
    Username:<input type="text" name="username" value=
    <%=@user.username%>"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password" value="
    <%=@user.password%>"><br>
   City:<input type="text" name="city" value="<%=@user.city%>">
     <br>
   Tell us more about you:<input type="text" name="description" 
     value="<%=@user.description%>"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="Update" class="btn btn-primary " >
</form>
```

Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

The form was passing the record id to the route, thus I modified the form to:

```
<form action="/users/edit/<%=@user.id%>" method="post" 
      id="edit">
```

and the route to:

```
put '/users/edit/:id' do
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @user.city= params[:city]
  # rest of the fields need to be modified
end
```